# spring: access properties set from <context:property-placeholder>

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am setting properties using:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="#{ T(System).getenv().get('DEV_PROPERTIES') ?: 'classpath:/META-INF/properties/config.properties' }"/>
```

I am able to access the properties:

```
@Value("${hostname}")
String hostname;`
```

This works fine.

However, i would like to access the properties using the property map or simple just get the values in a method which can't use `@Value` variables. Is there a way i can inject the property bean set using `<context:property-placeholder />`.?

Environment doesn't have the access to properties set from the properties file, it only can read properties from system and environment properties.

Comment: The short answer no you cannot access the properties from the property placeholder, you can however register a separate properties object and use that with the property placeholder. If you want to have them added to the `Environment` just use a `@PropertySource` on a `@Configuration` class to have it added.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot access the properties used internally by the `property-placeholder`. What you can do is load the properties into a `Properties` object and inject that into the `property-placeholder` and also inject it into whatever you like.

Another tip you don't need to use SpEL to achieve what you want in your `location` attribute, a simple placeholder would do the trick.

To load a properties object use the `util` namespace.

```
<util:properties id="props" location="${DEV_PROPERTIES:classpath:/META-INF/properties/config.properties}" />
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props" />
```

To make the properties you want available to the `Environment` you should use the `@PropertySource` annotation on a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("${DEV_PROPERTIES:classpath:/META-INF/properties/config.properties}")
public class ApplicationConfig { ... }
```

You can either add this as a bean to your xml file or have it detected while component scanning. Either way should work.